# Add line break via regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have a quite big text file (300k lines), which I am trying to process with Sublime Text, but open to alternatives (using mac).

I would need to add line breaks via regex matching the pattern '(1234567)' seven digits in a bracket. The text contains other content in brackets, where line breaks are not needed. I would like to split the text to each line start at the bracket:

Source:
lorem, Ipsum (1234567) — text of the printing and typesetting (something) 12345. lorem, Ipsum (1234567) — text of the printing and typesetting, lorem, Ipsum (1234567) — text of the printing and typesetting (something)

Target:

(1234567) — text of the printing and typesetting (something) 12345. lorem, Ipsum

(1234567) — text of the printing and typesetting, lorem, Ipsum

(1234567) — text of the printing and typesetting (something)

Would anyone know how to do it via regex find and replace or anyone could suggest an alternative?

Thank you!

Edit:
If it's easier to replace the leading (, that's also perfect.
Target:

1234567) — text of the printing and typesetting (something) 12345. lorem, Ipsum

1234567) — text of the printing and typesetting, lorem, Ipsum

1234567) — text of the printing and typesetting (something)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex in *Find*-section and **\n** in *Replace*-section:

```regex
(?=\(\d{7}\))
```

or if need to replace the leading brace:

```regex
\((?=\d{7}\))
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked via (?=\(\d{7}\))